# How to invoke a method in Ruby when the method name is dynamic?

Tags: ruby

```
@video = Video.new
thumb = "video_thumbnail"
@video_thumbnail = @video.video_thumbnail  ## works fine 
@video_thumbnail = @video.thumb            ## undefined method `thumb'
```

How can I call the `video_thumbnail` method dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby, you can use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) similar to this:

```
thumb = :video_thumbnail
@video_thumbnail = @video.send(thumb)
```

However, you should be aware of the potential security implications of this approach. If the contents of the `thumb` variable is in any way controllable by the user (e.g. by setting it from `params`), any user might have the possibility to call arbitrary methods on your video object. And given the large amount of meta-programming in Rails, you could easily have the ability to call and run arbitrary code that way. Because of that, you should make sure, that you tightly control the contents of the `thumb` variable.

If possible, you should user other means to call the methods, e.g. by using separate controller actions and proper routes to call them.

Answer (score 2):

You have `send()` to dynamically invoke methods (and `__send__` if the object may have overriden `send`)

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: `send` will happily invoke private methods

Comment: @Ven It still implies that `send` only works for public methods.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Uh, looks like I forgot to validate the change !