# String Literal in rails method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, parameters, escaping

How to pass a string literal to a ruby method? (Rails 2.3.8)
I want to achieve something like the below example:

```
 Class.find_by_"#{params[:column]}"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to invoke a method in ruby when method name is dynamic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749952/how-to-invoke-a-method-in-ruby-when-method-name-is-dynamic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Class.send(:"find_by_#{params[:column]}", value)
```

Comment: Why do you change `params[:column]` to string then to symbol?

Comment: @MrYoshiji - params[:column] is a string, so I'm not turning it into a string. I prefer passing symbols instead of strings to `send`, hence I am converting it to a symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.send("your_method", *your_args)`:

```
1.9.3p489 :027 > Object.send("try", :to_s)
 => "Object"
```

---

**In your case:**

```
Model.send("find_by_#{params[:column]}", params[:search_string])
```

---

Also, I **highly recommend you to put some security checks** on this:

```
if Model.column_names.include?(params[:column].to_s)
  Model.send("find_by_#{params[:column]}", params[:search_string])
else
  # usually return nil or empty scope like `Model.where('FALSE')`
end
```

This will prevent from using non-existing columns, and provoke a internal error in your app.

Comment: Hi Yoshiji, That is not working.I have to pass the query string too right

Comment: Hi @Stacked-for-life, can you post the error message?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
...(find_by_"#{params[:column]}"(params[:search_string]))

Comment: I am sending the column names through a different model method @MrYoshiji yes that would have been helpful though

Comment: @Stacked-for-life Remember one thing: "never trust user's input", I hope you will add a verification on what column the end-user is trying to search on

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4 - this should work:

```
column_name = params[:column]
Class.find_by column_name.to_sym => value
```

Comment: why do you change `column_name` to symbol and then back to string?

Comment: Makes no sense. Thanx!